# Gallery Lightbox/Colorbox Popup in View That only displays the first Image on the page

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to create a view that shows the first image from an unlimited content field "gallery_image", and that, when clicked on, shows the rest of the images from that field.  Is there a way to do this? I'm open to this not being a view either, just looking for the desired functionality where you see the first image from an unlimited field, and then see the rest in the lightbox.

I tried doing this with Lightbox2 setting only the first value to show up, but the lightbox shows all the images that are in the view in its entirety, and none of the other images from each field beyond the first one show up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to use CSS for this. There's 2 ways to do that:

Simply use the css :first-child selector to ensure all images are hidden except the first.

OR

Add 2 "gallery_image" fields to the view, and under the multiple field section in the settings for the first field, limit it to display only 1 value starting from 0. In the second, display all the values starting from 1. You could then create an image style to crop the image down to 1x1 pixels & then hide that entire field with CSS. Lightbox will go through all the images.

Regards, 
[VIS Design](http://visdesign.co.uk)